# Find records with similar fields value in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have 2 tables by this structure:

```
Table 1 :
  vID,
  PID,
  Year

Table 2:
   ID,
   vID, ( From Table 1 )
   StartTime,
   EndTime
```

relation between Table 1 and Table 2 is `1->*`.
We have about 5000 records in Table 1 and near to 9000 in Table 2.
Now we need to find all records in Table 1 which have same PID and same StartTime and EndTime and add a new column GroupCode to Table 1 and each group have a similar value.

Example of Values

```
Table 1
 vID     PID    Year
  1      100     2012
  2      101     2012
  3      100     2012
  4      101     2012
  5      100     2012

Table 2
    ID     vID   StartTime       EndTime
     1      1     2012-01-01       2012-02-01
     2      1     2012-05-01       2012-05-03
     3      2     2012-02-05       2012-02-07
     4      3     2012-01-01       2012-02-01
     5      3     2012-05-01       2012-05-03
     6      4     2012-02-05       2012-02-07
     7      5     2012-03-05       2012-05-01
```

in this example, record 1 and 3 in Table 1 must have GroupCode 1 , record 2 and 4 must have GroupCode=2 and record 7 must has GroupCode=3

Is there any query which can do this grouping in Sql server 2008?

Comment: What should happen if three vIDs have matching PIDs and Start/EndTimes? 

Like `vID1 and vID2 match` and `vID2 and vID3 match.` Will they be together in one big group or will vID2 have two GroupCodes?

Comment: they will be together in one big group, a group may have 3 or more records

Answer (score 0):

You can get the groups as follows...

```
select pid, starttime, endtime, ROW_NUMBER() over (order by min(id)) as groupcode
 from t1
    inner join t2 
        on t1.vid = t2.vid
group by pid, starttime, endtime
having COUNT(*)>1
```

Comment: if there is more than one related record in Table 2, result will be incorrect ( 2 or more groupCode for same vID)